# Is it possible to remove the checkbox from the power apps model driven welcome page?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, angularjs, model-driven

I have a model-driven app with a welcome page enabled and it's displayed whenever the app is launched.
In this welcome page, in the lower left corner, you have a checkbox to "Do not show this welcome page next time" as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

Therefore, is it possible to hide this highlighted checkbox using JS or any other language in order to make it mandatory, or it's not doable knowing that the only way to only access the code is from Inspect?

Any help would be really appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: If you do not have access to the app's source code, I think It is not possible to hide or remove the checkbox, especially if the code can only be accessed through Inspect.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I thought too but I'm making sure that it's doable , thanks man.